# Flutter Geofences

Tags: dart, flutter, geofencing

Is there a platform that allows me to create and monitor geofences and has a flutter API that enables me to detect whether a user using my Flutter app is within the perimeter of that geofence?

Comment: Ben Konyi made an awesome Geofencing plugin available here: https://github.com/bkonyi/FlutterGeofencing/ (it's not yet published a.f.a.i.k. so you need to reference it locally). It's developement is documented here: https://medium.com/flutter-io/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124?linkId=57902606

Answer (score 0):

Now Yes.

You can achieve that using [Geofence package](https://pub.dev/packages/geofence). It is left to you to implement the logic of getting notification when app is within a certain perimeter.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [geofence_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/geofence_flutter) package. It provides geofence event streams depending on user's current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [flutter_geofence](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_geofence), it provides geofence features based on user's realtime location.